# What could cause replication to break on MySQL when replicating from 5.7.40 to 8.0 replica

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, gtid

We have a MySQL primary running on 5.7.40. We are in process of testing the upgrade to 8.0.36 (this is on AWS RDS). We had 2 MySQL-8 replicas and 2 MySQL-5.7 replicas replicating from the primary.
At almost the same time, both the MySQL 8.0 replicas stopped replicating and complained on `HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY`

```
 Replica SQL for channel '': Worker 2 failed executing transaction '87953f5d-7595-11ed-830d-02f4790d85ab:57805008598' at source log mysql-bin-changelog.676514, end_log_pos 52858646; Could not execute Write_rows event on table ebdb.bike_issues; Duplicate entry '177235118' for key 'bike_issues.PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's source log mysql-bin-changelog.676514, end_log_pos 52858646, Error_code: MY-001062
```

Weirdly though the replicas complained on different key values, but the timestamp was nearly the same (few ms apart). The MySQL 5.7 replicas were fine, so clearly there was no hiccups on the primary side. Nothing shows up in the logs of primary around this time either.

The table, it complained on, is very commonly written table and we had this MySQL 8 replicas running for over a week now, without any replication issues.
We do Row-based, GTID based replication (gtid_mode ON, enforce_gtid_consistency ON)

I was able to resume replication by setting `slave_exec_mode` to `IDEMPOTENT` temporarily. When I check the error logs after the replication was in sync, I didn't see errors for the first replica's key in the second replicas error logs & vice versa i.e. they both failed on different keys. Could this be some issue on the replication receiver part? Or possibly some bug due to version mismatch? Or some mysql variable mismatch?

How can I debug this further? What could have possibly caused this blip?

**EDIT #1**

Output of create table
On Primary

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bike_issues` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `issue_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `bike_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reported_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `resolved_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `resolution_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `idempotency_key` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_bike_issues_on_token` (`token`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_bike_issues_on_idempotency_key` (`idempotency_key`),
  KEY `by_bike_id_issue_type_resolved_at` (`bike_id`,`issue_type`,`resolved_at`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_bike_issues_on_resolved_at` (`resolved_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=177614144 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

On MySQL 8 replica

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bike_issues` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `issue_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `bike_id` int NOT NULL,
  `reported_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `resolved_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `resolution_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `idempotency_key` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_bike_issues_on_token` (`token`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_bike_issues_on_idempotency_key` (`idempotency_key`),
  KEY `by_bike_id_issue_type_resolved_at` (`bike_id`,`issue_type`,`resolved_at`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_bike_issues_on_resolved_at` (`resolved_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=177614497 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

On Primary

```
show variables like '%binlog%';
+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                              | Value                |
+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| binlog_cache_size                          | 32768                |
| binlog_checksum                            | NONE                 |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates    | OFF                  |
| binlog_error_action                        | IGNORE_ERROR         |
| binlog_format                              | ROW                  |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_delay             | 0                    |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count    | 0                    |
| binlog_gtid_simple_recovery                | ON                   |
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time                | 0                    |
| binlog_order_commits                       | ON                   |
| binlog_row_image                           | FULL                 |
| binlog_rows_query_log_events               | OFF                  |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                     | 32768                |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size | 25000                |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking     | COMMIT_ORDER         |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                   | OFF                  |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog             | OFF                  |
| log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog           | OFF                  |
| max_binlog_cache_size                      | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                            | 134217728            |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                 | 18446744073709547520 |
| sync_binlog                                | 2000                 |
+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+
mysql> show variables like '%slave%';
+------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                 |
+------------------------------+-----------------------+
| init_slave                   |                       |
| log_slave_updates            | ON                    |
| log_slow_slave_statements    | ON                    |
| pseudo_slave_mode            | OFF                   |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout       | 31536000              |
| slave_allow_batching         | OFF                   |
| slave_checkpoint_group       | 512                   |
| slave_checkpoint_period      | 300                   |
| slave_compressed_protocol    | OFF                   |
| slave_exec_mode              | STRICT                |
| slave_load_tmpdir            | /rdsdbdata/tmp        |
| slave_max_allowed_packet     | 1073741824            |
| slave_net_timeout            | 60                    |
| slave_parallel_type          | DATABASE              |
| slave_parallel_workers       | 0                     |
| slave_pending_jobs_size_max  | 16777216              |
| slave_preserve_commit_order  | OFF                   |
| slave_rows_search_algorithms | TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN |
| slave_skip_errors            | OFF                   |
| slave_sql_verify_checksum    | ON                    |
| slave_transaction_retries    | 10                    |
| slave_type_conversions       |                       |
| sql_slave_skip_counter       | 0                     |
+------------------------------+-----------------------+
mysql> show variables where variable_name in  ('gtid_mode', 'enforce_gtid_consistency', 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit');
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                  | Value |
+--------------------------------+-------+
| enforce_gtid_consistency       | ON    |
| gtid_mode                      | ON    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 2     |
+--------------------------------+-------+
```

On MySQL 8.0 replica

```
mysql> show variables like '%binlog%';
+------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                                  | Value                |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| binlog_cache_size                              | 32768                |
| binlog_checksum                                | NONE                 |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates        | OFF                  |
| binlog_encryption                              | OFF                  |
| binlog_error_action                            | ABORT_SERVER         |
| binlog_expire_logs_auto_purge                  | ON                   |
| binlog_expire_logs_seconds                     | 2592000              |
| binlog_format                                  | ROW                  |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_delay                 | 0                    |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count        | 0                    |
| binlog_gtid_simple_recovery                    | ON                   |
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time                    | 0                    |
| binlog_order_commits                           | ON                   |
| binlog_rotate_encryption_master_key_at_startup | OFF                  |
| binlog_row_event_max_size                      | 8192                 |
| binlog_row_image                               | FULL                 |
| binlog_row_metadata                            | MINIMAL              |
| binlog_row_value_options                       |                      |
| binlog_rows_query_log_events                   | OFF                  |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                         | 32768                |
| binlog_transaction_compression                 | OFF                  |
| binlog_transaction_compression_level_zstd      | 3                    |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size     | 25000                |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking         | COMMIT_ORDER         |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                       | OFF                  |
| log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog               | OFF                  |
| max_binlog_cache_size                          | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                                | 134217728            |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                     | 18446744073709547520 |
| sync_binlog                                    | 1000                 |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
mysql> show variables where variable_name in  ('gtid_mode', 'enforce_gtid_consistency', 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit');
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                  | Value |
+--------------------------------+-------+
| enforce_gtid_consistency       | ON    |
| gtid_mode                      | ON    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 2     |
+--------------------------------+-------+
mysql> show variables like '%replica%';
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                                 | Value          |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+
| group_replication_consistency                 | EVENTUAL       |
| init_replica                                  |                |
| innodb_replication_delay                      | 0              |
| log_replica_updates                           | ON             |
| log_slow_replica_statements                   | OFF            |
| pseudo_replica_mode                           | OFF            |
| replica_allow_batching                        | ON             |
| replica_checkpoint_group                      | 512            |
| replica_checkpoint_period                     | 300            |
| replica_compressed_protocol                   | OFF            |
| replica_exec_mode                             | STRICT         |
| replica_load_tmpdir                           | /rdsdbdata/tmp |
| replica_max_allowed_packet                    | 1073741824     |
| replica_net_timeout                           | 60             |
| replica_parallel_type                         | LOGICAL_CLOCK  |
| replica_parallel_workers                      | 32             |
| replica_pending_jobs_size_max                 | 134217728      |
| replica_preserve_commit_order                 | ON             |
| replica_skip_errors                           | OFF            |
| replica_sql_verify_checksum                   | ON             |
| replica_transaction_retries                   | 10             |
| replica_type_conversions                      |                |
| replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config | OFF            |
| replication_sender_observe_commit_only        | OFF            |
| rpl_stop_replica_timeout                      | 31536000       |
| skip_replica_start                            | ON             |
| sql_replica_skip_counter                      | 0              |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL's `UUID()` function?  Let's see the table that is complaining.  What is toe topology -- effectively 4 Replicas and one Primary?

Comment: These version origination dates are years apart.  Many features have been added or deprecated over time.  You might want to start with SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name from both source and destination servers for comparison analysis.  There may be something about the table this is really not the same.  What is the TEXT result of SELECT @@binlog_format; from each server?

Comment: @RickJames yes, the topology is 1 Primary and 4 replicas. Primary and 2 replicas are on 5.7.40, 2 replicas on MySQL 8.0.36.  Added a bunch of info that could be relevant

Comment: File a bug report:  bugs.mysql.com

Comment: @RickJames Curious, what suggests we might have hit a bug?

Comment: @Rahul - Some questions cannot be handled by StackExchange; filing a "bug" may get you ah "answer", or may uncover an incompatibility between 5.7 and .8.0.  Has the issue happened more than once?  If so, how often?  Can you provide any common clues about the occurrences?

Comment: Got it, unfortunately we didn't have binary logs enabled on those replicas to make a good bug report. This has happened first time and only so far, we had the replica working for over a week. The only common things were, it was at the same time and same table, but different primary ids/keys on the two MySQL8 replica. Only MySQL 8 replicas failed, the MySQL 5.7s were fine. We had `STRICT` slave_exec_mode on all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We enabled binary logs and were able to figure this out when it happened again. The replica had `read_only=0` and an application level bug was doing writes in extremely rare scenarios.